# NullPointerException inside Context.getDrawable

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable, android-resources

So I just released a new beta today with no changes to this piece of code. Strangely enough I got a new crash I've never seen before reported on Crashlytics. It has only happened to 2 users from two different manufacturers on Android 6 and 7. So it isn't a huge deal yet but I would still like to get it fixed.

Anyone have any idea what might be the issue here?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.content.res.StringBlock.get(int)' on a null object reference
       at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:206)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1540)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:918)
       at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:463)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:30)
       at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:372)
```

Thanks. 
Here is the code that causes the issue:

```
@Override
    public Drawable getDefaultPlaceholderImage() {
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_placeholder);
    }
```

Comment: show us the code that caused the exception

Comment: Post ur code of this activity

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar crashes at some devices (Samsung GT-I9505, Android 5). The error happens while parsing xml of the image. The cause of the error is the number with two points in the xml (it was "1.84.63" in my xml). Try to create all xml of images by another converter (for example, Vector Asset Studio).